# sending complex objects using ksoap2

Tags: android

I'm building a mobile web-application.I have a web Service (WCF) and a android client.I send and receive messages using KSOAP2.So far I only needed to send simple stings and ints but the response was an array of complex objects,so i needed to parse it properly using this helpful [link](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.gr/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html).What i need to do now is the opposite,I need to send a complex object something like this:

```
public Class OutterObject{
       int a;
       String b;
       InnerObject c;
}
```

now the InnerObject also has two objects as fields.So it is kind of complicated.I have no idea of what i'm supposed to do,I've come accross some articles about marshaling but still i don't know if it is the right way to go since i've seen other articles that didn't use marshaling.Can you point me at the right direction?or share a guide of how to send complex objects using ksoap2.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks#sending/receiving_array_of_complex_types_or_primitives
The above link tells you how to send a complex object.
I also have found some stub-generator for ksoap2 or the other client. But no one can translate the complex object, except the wsclient++. However the wsclient++ is not for free.

Comment: well thanks for the response,seems i have to do a whole different thing now,I have to go with JSON thanks though for your response.